# Avoid mutating a prop directly (render function)

Tags: vuejs2, vue-render-function

just trying out creating components with the render function, but I am getting a weird warning:

[image]

Following component:

```
import Vue, { CreateElement, VNode } from 'vue'

export default Vue.extend({
  name: 'p-form-input',
  props: {
    type: String,
    name: String,
    value: {
      type: [ String, Number ]
    },
    placeholder: String,
    disabled: Boolean
  },
  data() {
    return {
      localValue: ''
    }
  },
  watch: {
    value(value) {
      this.localValue = value
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    this.localValue = this.$props.value
  },
  methods: {
    onInput(e: any) {
      this.localValue = e.target.value
      this.$emit('input', this.localValue)
    },
    onChange(e: any) {
      this.localValue = e.target.value
      this.$emit('change', this.localValue)
    }
  },
  render(h: CreateElement): VNode {
    return h('input', {
      class: 'form-control',
      domProps: {
        disabled: this.$props.disabled,
        type: this.$props.type,
        name: this.$props.name,
        placeholder: this.$props.placeholder,
        value: this.localValue
      },
      on: {
        input: this.onInput,
        change: this.onChange
      }
    })
  }
})
```

A `v-model="inputValue"` on the component does trigger a input/change on `inputValue` but im getting the warning?

Using vue 2.6.11!

Edit:

Don't mind the ts-ignore, it complains about no types found for it, so that's more cosmetic!!!

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <p-form-input type="text" name="some_input" v-model="inputValue" /> {{ inputValue }}
  </div>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import Vue from 'vue'
// @ts-ignore
import PFormInput from 'vue-components/esm/components/form-input'

export default Vue.extend({
  name: 'App',
  components: {
    PFormInput,
  },
  data() {
    return {
      inputValue: 'fdsdsfdsf'
    }
  }
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a prop named "value' and then you are using a variable named "value" in your method:

```
    onInput(e: any) {
      const value = e.target.value

      this.localValue = value

      this.$emit('input', value)
    },
```

Don't reuse the name "value".  In fact, you don't even need that variable:

```
    onInput(e: any) {
      this.localValue = e.target.value
      this.$emit('input', this.localValue)
    },
```

Same thing for onChange:

```
    onChange(e: any) {
      this.localValue = e.target.value
      this.$emit('change', this.localValue)
    }
```

Comment: I don't see anything else in the posted code.  Can you post the code where you have PFormInput?

Comment: The error you posted references PFormInput, but I do not see PFormInput in the OP.  Could you perhaps add the code where PFormInput is referenced?

Comment: The code I posted is the PFormInput component (as you can see the name property)!
`name: 'p-form-input'`

Comment: Sorry, to be more clear, I was hoping to see the code that actually uses the PFormInput (i.e. the location where you have <PFormInput>)  With a bit more code I may be able to reproduce the issue, which would very helpful.